# How to export asp.net page to pdf with radio buttons selected and text box data using any dll in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to export asp.net page to pdf.My web page is a form where user enters some data in text boxes and radio buttons.I tried to export to PDF using Itextsharp dll but alignment is not at all perfect.And am not getting radio buttons in PDF.If I take only selected item from radio buttons list and displayed in a label then huge alignment problem.I have used below code,plz check and suggest me.

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        dt.Columns.Add("REquestType");
        dt.Columns.Add("Name");
        dt.Rows.Add();
        if (rbtlstRqstType.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            dt.Rows[0]["REquestType"] = rbtlstRqstType.SelectedItem.Text;
        }
        dt.Rows[0]["Name"] = txtFname.Text;

        lbllstRqstType.Text = dt.Rows[0]["REquestType"].ToString();
        lblName.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Name"].ToString();


    }

try
{


            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=IDform.pdf");
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

            rbtlstRqstType.Visible = false;
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            //this.Page.RenderControl(hw);
            pnlIDForm.RenderControl(hw);
            StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());

            Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 100f, 0f);
            HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
            pdfDoc.Open();
            htmlparser.Parse(sr);
            pdfDoc.Close();
            Response.Write(pdfDoc);
            Response.End();

}
```

Comment: I wouldn't render directly your HTML page...You may use **another** HTML page specifically made to be converted to PDF filled with data from your original page...

Comment: You can now generate pdf directly from mvc view; Find details from http://stackoverflow.com/a/29512988/1390955

Answer (score 0):

Create a PDF template, containing a form.

Add the form fields, and then populate the form fields using C# and iTextSharp, something like:

```
    acroFields.SetField("CustomerName", customer.Name);
    acroFields.SetField("BranchName", customer.Branch);
```

Comment: Thank You Joe....I am not getting you..could you please elaborate your solution....

Comment: Create a PDF using Adobe Acrobat that matches your web page, then you have complete control over the PDF format and layout. Add a form and the relevant fields to the PDF in Adobe Acrobat. Then simply populate the fields using iTextSharp.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Rotativa](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rotativa) which is design to generate PDF in MVC application.

You can get all documents regarding methods and demo from https://github.com/webgio/Rotativa

Comment: Thank you....but I want to develop in plain Asp.Net with out MVC...Am almost achieved but facing problem only in alignment.

Comment: With this tool you can parse html as a pdf file. it is not limited to MVC only